# dat.GUI and Three.js: dat is not defined

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I can't make it including a dat.GUI element in my project.

Even placing a

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
```

makes my Three.js geometry disappear

"dat is not defined"

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these things:

- Have you imported the library correctly? It's not included in three.js;
- Check out the GUI constructor. In some older versions it was DAT.GUI(), then it became dat.GUI(),so check the library version you're using.